# tmux and xf86 keys (the 'Fn' key, xf86WakeUp)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, xmodmap

I'm interested in hijacking the Fn key on my laptop and using it as the mod key for tmux, but after a bunch of tinkering with xmodmap and tmux.config, I'm not much further along in getting this to work.

- xev shows that they key name is XF86WakeUp, but this doesn't work as a key in tmux.config.
- I've tried setting the hex code for XF86WakeUP (0xF8) in tmux, but this doesn't work either.
- I know that the Fn key sending its own code is something of a fluke, but it's a fluke I'd like to take advantage of now and worry about the consequences later (it's a valuable key in a valuable space!)

Answer (score 6):

You are probably using a Lenovo keyboard, which reports the <kbd>Fn</kbd> as `XF86WakeUp`. Normally <kbd>Fn</kbd> does not register an `xev` event at all because it is handled by the BIOS, therefore you **cannot** remap it.

The fact that it is reported as `XF86WakeUp` gives a lot of confusion, as you can see in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotkey-setup/+bug/287428), but it is not really a bug, to quote [comment 27](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotkey-setup/+bug/287428/comments/27) of that bug report:

> It's not really a bug. <kbd>Fn</kbd> *is* the wakeup key when the machine is suspended. If anyone wants to map it to other functions, then that's okay, but being able to do that is not universal... <kbd>Fn</kbd> on ThinkPads and LenovoPads is a magical/special key. It only generates its own code if not combined with any of the other magic (blue highlighted) key combinations and that is more of a fluke than anything.

[(Source)](https://askubuntu.com/a/347910)